# How to use well scipy.optimize.fmin

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization, minimize

Hello I'm trying tu use scipy.optimize.fmin to minimize a function. But things aren't going well since my computation seems diverging instead of converging and i got an error. I tried to fixed a tolerance but it is not working.
Here is my code (Main program):

```
import sys,os
import numpy as np
from math import exp
import scipy
from scipy.optimize import fmin

from carlo import *

A=real()

x_r=0.11245
x_i=0.14587

#C=A.minim
part_real=0.532
part_imag=1.2
R_0 = fmin(A.minim,[part_real,part_imag],xtol=0.0001)
```

And the class:

```
import sys,os
import numpy as np
import random, math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cmath
#import pdb
#pdb.set_trace()

class real:
    def __init__(self):
        self.nmodes = 4
        self.L_ch = 1
        self.w = 2

    def minim(self,p):

        x_r=p[0]
        x_i=p[1]
        x=complex(x_r,x_i)
        self.a=complex(3,4)*(3*np.exp(1j*self.L_ch))
        self.T=np.array([[0.0,2.0*self.a],[(0.00645+(x)**2), 4.3*x**2]])
        self.Id=np.array([[1,0],[0,1]])
        self.disp=np.linalg.det(self.T-self.Id)
        print self.disp
        return self.disp
```

The error is:

```
(-2.16124712985-8.13819476595j)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py:438: ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part
  fsim[0] = func(x0)
(-1.85751684826-8.95377303768j)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py:450: ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part
  fsim[k + 1] = f
(-2.79592712985-8.13819476595j)
(-3.08484130014-7.36240080015j)
(-3.68788935914-6.62639114029j)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py:475: ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part
  fsim[-1] = fxe
(-2.62046851255e+87-1.45013007728e+88j)
(-4.037931857e+87-2.2345341712e+88j)
(-7.45017628087e+87-4.12282179854e+88j)
(-1.14801242605e+88-6.35293780534e+88j)
(-2.11813751435e+88-1.17214723347e+89j)
Warning: Maximum number of function evaluations has been exceeded.
```

Actually I don't undersatnd why the computation is diverging, maybe I have to use something else instead of using fmin for minimizing?
Someone got an idea?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Class names should named using CapWords - http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names

Comment: @IanAuld it's a guideline, not a law.

Comment: You are returning complex numbers from the objective function. What would minimization of a complex number even mean? Is 1+2j < 2+1j, is it >, or are they equal? Fmin is here taking the real part -- as you see, it is nicely minimizing it towards -infinity

Answer (score 2):

Try to optimize the absolute value instead of the complex value. That gave decent result for me.

```
f = lambda x: abs(A.minim(x))
R_0 = fmin(f,[part_real,part_imag],xtol=0.0001)
```

I guess fmin don't work well with complex values.